# How do virtual methods work in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I know in C++ there are vpointer and vtable.
The virtual function table  is a list of method pointers to the virtual methods in the class.
Each instance of a class has a pointer to the table, which is used when we call a virtual method from the instance.

I want to know how this implemented in C#. As I know the concept of virtual tables are the same. But what about vpointer is GetType() is used instead.

I would appreciate as much details as possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vtables are one possible approach in C++, they are *not* mandated by the C++ standard. The approach .NET uses clearly meets the published standards for the CLI and C#, but the implementation details are not specified (and could potentially change).

You can infer some details from the way that interfaces, overridden members and "new" members work.

Why do you want to know this? If you have a specific problem then stating the problem will allow others to address that directly.

Comment: There is no particular problem to be solved I just want to know how it is working/implemented internally.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at their documentation in the [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645596(v=VS.71).aspx): [10.5.3 Virtual Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=VS.71).aspx) (although it's the *spec* not the implementation).