# How does variable know about the type it implements?

Tags: c#

As I know, each variable knows about its runtime type.

Here is an example:

```
void Main()
{
    C c = new C();
    c.M();
    I i = (I)c;
    i.M();
}

public interface I
{
    void M();
}

public class C : I
{
    void I.M() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I.M");
    }

    public void M() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("M");
    }
}
```

If I understand it right, `i` still knows that its type is `C`. So, what is the mechanism which lets `i` to decide on using `I.M` instead of `M`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation

Comment: Just to clarify your terminology: a *variable* knows only what its type restriction is. A variable of reference type can have a *value* which is a *valid reference* to an *object* (or a null reference, to no object.) It is the *object* that knows what its runtime type is.

Comment: The concept behind it is called [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do virtual methods work in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311012/how-do-virtual-methods-work-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to know how *runtime method binding* works, that is, how does the runtime know to call one method M instead of another when there was not enough information at compile time to encode into the program precisely which method to call?

Here's a good exercise: try to write a program that has that behaviour *without using the feature as it is already written in the runtime*. By doing that you will gain insight into how the people implementing the runtime did it.

I go through this exercise for virtual functions here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/17/implementing-the-virtual-method-pattern-in-c-part-one.aspx

Read that series and you'll see how you could emulate virtual dispatch in a language that does not have it.  The basic idea that I show in the articles is more or less how virtual dispatch actually works in C#.  Interface dispatch is a bit trickier in practice but the concept is basically the same.

Answer (score 8):

Internally each object has its own TypeHandle, see object internal structure below:

[MSDN - Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx)

[image]